# How to retrieve multiline secret from Azure secrets into GitHub actions?

Tags: jwt, github-actions, azure-keyvault

I have a private key stored in file and retrieving content to authenticate using salesforce JWT in GitHub actions ,now I want to store the key in azure secrets and retrieve into GitHub actions
I have created multiline secret as:

*az keyvault secret set --vault-name "mySecretVault" --name "SecretKey" --file "./Actions/workflow/secret.key"*

Secret got created and in GitHub actions, an error is thrown while retrieving secret as:

```
  - uses: Azure/login@v1
    with:
      creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
      allow-no-subscriptions: true
  - uses: Azure/get-keyvault-secrets@v1
    with:
      keyvault: "mySecretVault"
      secrets: "SecretKey"
    id: myGetSecretAction
```

Error:
***ParserError: /home/runner/work/_temp/22683ae6ac8264a89.ps1:1
24Line |
25 |+DL…..
26 | ~
27 | Missing expression after unary operator '+'.***

Since the default encoding is UTF-8, I have also tried creating secret using ASCII encoding, but same error. There are also other single line secrets, they are working fine.
How to retrieve multiline secret from Azure key vault into GitHub actions?

Comment: Do you recognize the `+DL[...]26` string in the error message? Is it the secret you are pulling?

Comment: Yes, it is in middle of secret and those characters are beginning of a line

Comment: Is it possible the error is not thrown by the `Azure/get-keyvault-secrets@v1` action, but by another step consuming the secret? Where are you using this secret and what does that usage look like?

Comment: Error is being thrown at the mentioned step, no error is thrown if this step is removed

Comment: How can there be no error thrown if the step is removed? No other step relies on the secret being correctly pulled?

Comment: Assuming you are using it in another step like so, `${{ steps.myGetSecretAction.outputs.SecretKey }}`. If that is the case, it is possible that whatever process is consuming this is the one throwing as it interprets the `+` char as an operation. If I had to guess, I'd try maybe quoting the secret, `"${{ steps.myGetSecretAction.outputs.ScretKey }}"` (notice the quotes).

Comment: If you remove the step "consuming" the secret, is it still throwing the error?

Comment: Yes, it is still throwing the error even after removing “consuming” step, consuming step is same as you mentioned above